# jquery trim text value and format

Tags: jquery, format, trim

I have some jquery which grabs an elements id and places it into a textbox

The id of the textbox is automatically set so i can't change it.

I'm trying to trim the id and then format it so that it reads properly

Here's my HTML

```
<a id="day_2294_110_2011-6-2" class="weekday" href="javascript:;">Day</a>

<input type="text" id="therapydate" />
```

And my jQuery

```
$('.weekday').click(function() {

    $('#therapydate').val($(this).attr('id'));

});
```

This puts the value of my textbox to `day_2294_110_2011-6-2` but i'd like to remove this `day_2294_110_` and just be left with `2011-6-2` and then format that as a date like this `2nd June 2011` or `02/06/2011`

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this(gives you the date in MM/DD/YYYY format):

```
var id = $('#therapydate').val($(this).attr('id')); 
var requiredOP = id.replace(/.*_(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)$/, '$2/$3/$1');
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/L42Lq/

Comment: really nice solution ! once you got your date you can use the date format code found here http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format
and when jsut use YourResult = dateFormat(YOUR-DATE, "dS mmmm yyyy"); and it will return 2nd June 2011

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could use the string.split() method to break it up into an array, in this case the array would contain 4 elements and the last element is the piece you want.

Something like:

```
    var splitId = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    $('#therapydate').val(splitId[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
var date = new Date ("day_2294_110_2011-6-2".substring(13, 21)).toUTCString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @Cybernate's solution.

```
$('.weekday').click(function() {
    var date = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#therapydate').val(date.slice(date.lastIndexOf("_")+1, date.length));
});
```

[Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/mYXfa/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get the date inside this id in many ways. You could try using regExp, split per '-' or even using substring function.
After this, to format your date properly, you could try this: 
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Answer (score 0):

You can `split()` on an underscore and grab the last item in the array:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id'));
var parts = id.split('_');
var datePart = parts[parts.length-1];
```

You can alternatively get the last index of the underscore and then grab a substring of everything to the right of it:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id'));
var index = id.lastIndexOf('_') + 1;
var datePart = id.substr(index);
```

There's a lot of date formatting documentation out there.  Just google around.  For example:  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat